# passing arguments with a call back function

Tags: javascript, function, callback

```
function images(url, somextra, callback)
{
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        callback(url , somextra);   
    };
}

function call(url, extra)
{
}

images(someurl, stuffs, call);
```

When I am passing 2 arguments my programs just hangs. How can I pass two arguments and a callback function in my images function?

Comment: It's not the "two arguments", this would act just the same with one argument. You're not loading the image at all... try adding `img.src = url` or something.

Comment: your code just seems to pass arguments with a callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear you concept !!!! it does not matters if one or more than one argument.

```
img.src = url
```

try to add image url after imag.onload

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a the callback up on the onload event, but you are not loading the image.

Try setting up the source for the image like this.

```
function images(url ,somextra , callback)
{
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
         callback(url , somextra);   
    };
    // set the source url here
    img.src = "example/url/image.png"
 }

 function call(url , extra){

 }
 images( someurl , stuffs , call);
```

Otherwise your onload event never fires and therefore the callback is not called.